# Write in polar form

Tags: polar-coordinates

I've been giving the the following: $$z = -3e^{-i\pi/5}$$

How do I write that in polar form?

I understand that -3 is not correct, since the absolute distance must be $\ge 0$.

What do I need to do to solve it? Should I try to write it in rectangular form?

The answer is $z = 3e^{i4\pi/5}$

Comment: It's sitting in polar form already. Meaning you can look at it and get $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: @JohnD It is not supposed to be -3

Comment: Use the famous $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Answer (score 5):

$$
z = -3 e^{-i \pi/5} = 3(-1) e^{-i \pi/5} = 3 e^{i\pi} e^{-i \pi/5} = 3 e^{-i \pi/5 + i \pi} = 3 e^{i4\pi/5}
$$